# SSIS Capture OLEDB error in dataflow task

Tags: ssis

I am wondering if there a way to capture `OLEDB` error in code, as they are showing on progress message. The system variable `"ErrorCode"` and `"ErrorCodeDescription"` is too brief.

I would like to use a script component to save the failed row data with real error message (in my case is `OLEDB` error) to my log table. If I could get the `OLEDB` error message on certain event then I could just save it in an user variable and use the variable in my script component.

progress message

[image: progress message]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can give this a try? Let us know if it works. 
[Capturing and Logging SSIS Errors](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2149/capturing-and-logging-data-load-errors-for-an-ssis-package/)